# How can you invoke a MetalPerformanceShadersGraph directly from Metal Shaders?

Tags: neural-network, shader, metal, raytracing

There are many resources on Apple's developer documentation showing how to use Metal from Swift for ML to infer, or more specifically how to call a Metal Performance Shader graph of a neural network to predict some result. However, all of these examples, like the one linked below start from Swift.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshadersgraph/training_a_neural_network_using_mps_graph

```swift
    func encodeInferenceCase(sourceTensorData: MPSGraphTensorData) -> MPSGraphTensorData {
        let fetch = graph.run(with: gCommandQueue,
                              feeds: [sourcePlaceholderTensor: sourceTensorData],
                              targetTensors: targetInferenceTensors,
                              targetOperations: targetInferenceOps)

        return fetch[targetInferenceTensors[0]]!
    }
```

How can you invoke a graph, like the one above, when already in Metal Shader? This way you don't have to pay the cost of switching back and forth between the CPU and GPU. The context for this is for ray tracing, and using models to help predict global illumination. NVidia's more complicated version is linked below.

https://research.nvidia.com/publication/2021-06_real-time-neural-radiance-caching-path-tracing

Comment: There's no way to do this. If you want to issue commands on GPU timeline, you must use your own kernels and encode indirect command buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you cannot invoke a `Metal Performance Shader` from a `Metal` shader.

But assuming you already have a `Metal` device object, a command queue and tensors the CPU overhead should be minimal.

If that isn't acceptable for your application, you would have to implement your own graph operation(s) as `Metal` function(s).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Interesting. Given that I would want to infer every frame, even a minimal CPU switch would be cost prohibitive.

Do you have any links or further reading for how to implement graph operations in Metal. Is there perhaps some open source PyTorch stuff that can be reused?

Comment: CPU's are quite capable these days. Have you ran a trial and determined it is cost prohibitive? I suppose you could implement open source algorithms but please be sure to comply with the licenses. What specific graph functions do you require?